# Php: Inserting code into the xth item of product list

Tags: php

I am displaying a list of products and I want to insert an Ad as the xth item. So for example I have 20 items. I want to display an AD where the 5th item would normally be. It should not replace the 5th item, but just push the 5th item to the 6th spot and so on.

The code I have so far is this:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                <div class="product-layout product-grid col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="product-block">
                    <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="caption">
                        <h4><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
                        <p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>

                 </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just splice it into the array before iterating over it.

```php
<?php array_splice($products, 4, 0, $advertisement); ?>
```